# iTunes Connect Export Compliance

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am submitting an app to iTunes for the first time. Final stage has a question

> Export Compliance
>
> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or
>   incorporate cryptography? (Select Yes even if your app is only
>   utilizing the encryption available in iOS or OS X.)

I am using game center in my app for leaderboards. Does the authentication procedure(in-built) for game center make it necessary to answer the above question as "YES"?

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind, put that as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why the answer is no was that services such as Game Center, in-app purchase, etc... are provided by the iOS.  Your app did not involved in encryption/decryption of any user password.